# Where can I take the photos of Warsaw Skyline at night?

Tags: photography, nightlife, warsaw

Where can I take the photos of Warsaw Skyline at night?[image]

I know that this is taken somewhere from across Vistula river. But can you tell me from which location I should try?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the buildings - to have the Novotel (blue-lit building) to the left of the Palace of Culture, and in front of the big pointy building (I don't know what that is!), it would need to be taken almost due east of that group of buildings - putting it on the beach just north of Most Łazienkowski.

Comment: But as the Vistula river is so far away from the buildings, can the reflection form on the river?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing! It seems too far to me, similarly the perspective doesn't seem right either, but that might be down to the type of lens he's used...

Answer (score 1):

I am almost sure, that this photo is taken from Siekierkowski Bridge